# Find Files on Directory Tree based off a text list python

Tags: python, shutil, os.walk

I feel like I've found very similar questions and scripts but none that quite exactly hits the nail on the head.

Ideally, the script I been trying to write is to find files based off a list in a txt, and copy said file(s) to a directory.

EXAMPLE

/volumes/dir/dir/dir/dir (is my working directory)
That last part of cwd has many different directories such as abc, xyz, tuv, and each one of those has more subdirectories with the same first 3 letters. [Examples - abc0123, abc234, abc8940] Those numbered folders have more directories such as "reference, jpg, mov" in all of them.

The script I been trying to write is from ".txt" document containing file names abc0123.mov, xyz2330.mov, abc8940.mov on my "/users/desktop/dir/.txt" find in "/volumes/dir1/dir2dir3/dir3/" based off txt.

I imagine the file paths would look something like this...

**"*/volumes/dir1/dir2dir3/dir3/3_letter_folder(abc)/abc0123/abc0123_mov/abc0123.mov***(file on my txt document)" copy this file and move/copy to ***"/volumes/dir1/dir2/destination_folder"***

---Example Code---

`os.chdir('/Users/user/Desktop/Text_folder')`

`f = open('copy.txt', 'r')
for file_contents in f.readlines():
    print(f)
    f.close()`

`os.chdir('/Volumes/dir1/dir2/dir3/')`

`Main = ('destination_folder_path')`

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
print('root', root)
print('subdirs', subdirs)
print('files', files)
for file in files:
    path = os.path.join(root, file)
    shutil.copy(path, Main
```

I imagine Im missing a step or probably many after printing the document contents. I'm still very new to python but I'm trying to learn!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show the script you wrote? Please take a look at how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Absolutely sorry it took me so long I was learning to navigate and add the code!